# Create an xml file and return it from web service in visual basic

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hi I'm a very big begginer to VB and I cannot figure out how to return the result from the XML writer back to the client. I've used the string writer to create the format but I don't know how to RETURN it in a format that doesn't give an error.

```
Dim str_returnstring As New StringBuilder()
Using string_writer As New StringWriter(str_returnstring)
    Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(string_writer)
        writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
        writer.WriteStartElement("playlists")
        Dim var_arrayposition = 0
        For Each arr_playlistid In arr_playlistids
            writer.WriteStartElement("playlist")
            writer.WriteStartElement("playlistid")
            Dim int2string = Convert.ToString(arr_playlistid)
            writer.WriteString(int2string)
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteStartElement("playlistame")
            writer.WriteString(arr_playlistnames(var_arrayposition))
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            var_arrayposition += 1

            writer.WriteEndElement()
        Next
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteEndDocument()
    End Using

End Using
```

Comment: can you please include the full function and clarify how you're setting up the web service?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a [.NET Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hs6sw69(v=vs.90).aspx) then returning your XML as a response from one of the `WebMethod` functions should be as simple as:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function GetXML() As String
    'Your XML Generating Code Here
    Return str_returnstr.ToString()
End Function
```

Basically, inside your web service you declare a number of methods with the `<WebMethod()>` attribute attached. Those are the methods your web service exposes to requestors. To return data in a response to a call to one of these methods, just `Return` the way you normally would from a method call, and the background code will take care of the rest for you.